# How to write a generic for config object that exposes a function with argument that references the return value of the defined object properties

Tags: typescript

I want to define a function that is used to define an object config map, that is able to reference the computed the return value of other already defined function properties on the object, It will be used somewhat like this

```
const r = defineServiceRegistryItems({

  greeting: [() => 'Hello World'],
  
  sayHelloWorld: [({ servicelocatorImpl }) => {
    // goal is to get type safety even within the config map, and infer the return type
    return servicelocatorImpl.get('greeting')
  }]

})
```

Here's my attempt at typing this

```
type RegistryDefinition<T, C> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: [
    <R extends unknown>(args: {
      config: C;
      servicelocatorImpl: Locator<
        {
          [K in Exclude<keyof T, Prop>]: ReturnType<
            RegistryDefinition<T, C>[K][0]
          >;
        }
      >;
    }) => R
  ];
};
```

assuming `Locator` is defined as

```
class Locator<T = Record<string, unknown>> {
    get<K extends keyof T>(serviceName: K): T[K];
}
```

```
defineServiceRegistryItems<T>(registryConfig: RegistryDefinition<T>) => registryConfig
```

This approach sort of produces the experience I'm looking for but is incomplete, I know for `defineServiceRegistryItems` I should probably constrain T as a subset of `RegistryDefinition` but that introduces a whole lot of problems I couldn't figure out

Comment: Probably you don't need the `R` generic, just make the return type `T[Prop]`. Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGkpKW) what you are trying to do? If not, please provide more details and errors you are experiencing, because I can't suggest anything better for now

Comment: @AlexChashin specifying `T[Prop]` in place of `R` does not work unfortunately, you'll notice in the playground link you provided  hovering over the value of `r` that hello has a type of `string` but the value of `sayHelloWorld` gets inferred as `unknown` although the locator provides the correct return type. 

EDIT: in fact any register function that uses function params has an unknown return type